# How can I add custom class to menu item in WordPress. Below is my code, it does not work

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

header.php

```
/*Render menu*/
<div class="main-nav">
   <?php wp_nav_menu( 
     array( 
     'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
     'container' => 'ul',
     'menu_class' => 'nav'
     ) 
   ); 
   ?>
</div>
```

functions.php

```
/*Register menu*/
function register_main_menu(){
 register_nav_menus(array(
    'Primary' => __('Header Menu'),
    'Footer' => __('Footer Menu')
 ));
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'register_main_menu');

/*Custom menu class*/
function add_class_to_li($classes, $item){
  $classes[] = "nav-item";
  return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class','add_class_to_li', 10, 4);
```

This does not add 'nav-item' class to 'li'. Is there anything that I need to update.

Answer (score 0):

Your theme_location should be exactly like the one you have in your functions.php file. So your reader menu will be:

```
/*Render menu*/
<div class="main-nav">
   <?php wp_nav_menu( 
     array( 
     'theme_location' => 'Primary',  //this will be Primary, not header-menu
     'container' => 'ul',
     'menu_class' => 'nav'
     ) 
   ); 
   ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This was sharp! It was silly mistake from me. I should have read documenation correctly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great to know that it helped you! We sometimes do these mistakes and it's natural.